# Building a commercial website using wordpress

Tags: wordpress

does anyone know what building a WordPress commercial website actually means? Does it involve just learning PHP or other programming langs? Tried looking online, but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use wordpress to make a commerical/non blog website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520206/how-to-use-wordpress-to-make-a-commerical-non-blog-website)

Answer (score 0):

WordPress is a blogging platform available under a license which allows reuse. Anyone can download the WordPress source code and use it to make a website. This may be a commercial website.

WordPress allows plugins. Many plugins are available under the same licence as WordPress itself, or similar licenses. Others can be purchased. Or you can write your own or pay someone to write them for you. These plugins can radically change the behaviour of a WordPress site. You can build all kinds of complex applications on top of WordPress.

Whether this is a good idea is another question. In my opinion, WordPress is a decent blogging platform, and the well known shop plugins are well tested and probably reasonably well behaved, but using it as a basis for bespoke complex applications is a bad idea. It certainly can be done, but the data structure tends to be *weird*. I speak as someone who has rebuilt from scratch a couple of applications originally based on WordPress, and both times wasted hours of my life trying to make sense of the database.

Answer (score -1):

As per my opinion wordpress is not suitable for enterprise level applications, because due to lot of data it will get slow your site.
However if someone want to built commercial website on wordpress but on smaller scope, yes he/she can build on wordpress.

Building a commercial website on wordpress requires php basic knowledge and wordpress theme hiearchy and tags knowledge.

You do not need any high skill knowledge to build your commercial website.
Yes its involved learning of different fields like html, css, javascript or jquery, php, mysql.

But it depends on requirement.
If you have purchased a ready made theme and require only small changes then it will require frontend skills like html, css, jquery.
And if its need heavy customization then it will require backend skills like php or wordpress loop structure and theme structure.

Comment: Best not to answer opinion-soliciting questions (which are, by definition, off-topic). There are plenty of people who use WordPress within their enterprise environment. And skillsets for a web application vary widely. There's simply no way to provide an objective answer to the question.